# Show that if a m x n complex matrix U has orthonormal columns (in complex inner product), then for any x in $R^n$, ||Ux||=||x||

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that if a $m \times n$ complex matrix $U$ has orthonormal columns (in complex inner product), then  for any $x$ in $\mathbb R^n$, $\|Ux\|=\|x\|$.

I'm really stuck on this question.

Comment: Hint: If $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)^T$ and $C_j$ is the $j$th column of $U$ then $Ux=x_1C_1+\dots+x_nC_n$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich So $||Ux|| = ||x_1C_1||+...+||x_nC_n||=||x_1||+...+||x_n|| = ||x||$?

Comment: No. Second hint: Before trying to solve a problem regarding the norm of a vector you need to learn the definition of the norm of a vector.

Comment: Isn't  $||x_1C_1+...+x_nC_n|| \le ||x_1C_1||+...+||x_nC_n||$? Then $||x_1C_1||+...+||x_nC_n|| =\sqrt{(x_1C_1)^2}+...+\sqrt{(x_nC_n)^2} = ||x_1||+...+||x_n||$ (because $(C_j)^2 = 1$) $\ge ||x||$

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich See my previous comment.